# Reading from .can files

Tags: qt, parsing

I want to read .can files in Qt, I found out it is similiar to ini files so i used `QSettings::IniFormat`, i look for 2 attributes( say "rate" and "name").
code:

```js
for(int i=0; i<files.count();i++)
      {
          QSettings file(files[i], QSettings::IniFormat);
          QStringList keys = file.allKeys();
          foreach(const QString& key, keys)
          {
          if(key.endsWith("/rate"))
          {
          QString Rate = file.value(key).toString();
          qDebug() << Rate;
          }
          if(key.endsWith("/name"))
          {
              QString name = file.value(key).toString();
              qDebug()<<name;
          }
```

Problem is my can files has lot of "name" attribute, so this method is returning all the "name" attributes. I want to store the "name" attribute which the program finds right after "rate", there can be "name" attribute before "rate", so i just want to store the attribute which the program finds immediately after it finds "rate".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about `.can` files, I searched a little about them but couldn't find anything about them related to `ini` format.

Anyways, I rewrote your code to output the very first `name` attribute it finds after each `rate` encountered.

```
bool rateAttrFound = false;
for(int i=0; i<files.count();i++)
{
    QSettings file(files[i], QSettings::IniFormat);
    QStringList keys = file.allKeys();
    foreach(const QString& key, keys)
    {
        if(key.endsWith("/rate"))
            rateAttrFound = true;
        if(key.endsWith("/name"))
        {
            if(rateAttrFound){
                qDebug() << file.value(key).toString();
                rateAttrFound = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: They are not related, just that the format is kind of similiar.